# Proof of "If a Suslin line exists, then a Suslin tree exists." in Kunen's Set Theory

Tags: set-theory

I have a question about the theorem "If a Suslin line exists, then a Suslin tree exists.".
I am having trouble understanding the proof given in Theorem 5.13(page 72) of Kunen's set theory.

Specifically, I am having difficulty with the proof on page 73, where the definition of ${\cal I}_{\alpha+1}$ is given, and the proof that $\bigcup {\cal I}_{\alpha+1}$ is dense in $L$.

I tried searching for the proof online and found some hits:
[https://www.math.wustl.edu/~nweaver/forcing.pdf](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Enweaver/forcing.pdf), Lemma 15.3,
[https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/~hart/onderwijs/set_theory/Jech/09-combinatorial_set_theory.pdf](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/onderwijs/set_theory/Jech/09-combinatorial_set_theory.pdf), Lemma 9.14,
https://helda.helsinki.fi/server/api/core/bitstreams/bf960b17-77a1-47a0-8e53-01f6840be6ab/content, Theorem 4.4,
[https://people.math.ethz.ch/~halorenz/4students/Begleitseminar/SuslinLine.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ehalorenz/4students/Begleitseminar/SuslinLine.pdf), Lemma 20.3.

However, all of them seem to follow the same approach, which is different from Kunen's proof. Additionally, it should be noted that the definition of Suslin tree varies slightly between Kunen's and the latter 4 examples.

Is it possible that Kunen's proof is incorrect?
I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an issue in Kunen's proof. He constructs the tree level by level, while your other sources construct the tree by adding nodes here and there (this is also what Kunen does in his new edition; clearly you are reading the old edition), but I think essentially they are not that different. Here is what Kunen does. Consider a maximal collection $\mathcal{I}_0$ of disjoint open intervals of form $(a,b)$; these will be the roots of the tree (or forest). At successor step, for each $I\in\mathcal{I}_\alpha$ consider a maximal collection of disjoint open intervals $J$ of $I$; we also require that the closure of $J$ is contained in $I$, equivalently if $I=(a,b)$ then $J$ should be of form $(c,d)$ where $a<c<d<b$; these intervals belong to $\mathcal{I}_{\alpha+1}$ and are the immediate successors of $I$. The denseness of $\mathcal{I}_{\alpha+1}$ follows by induction.

At a limit stage $\gamma$, roughly speaking, we take intersections along all branches of the tree constructed thus far. Each intersection gives a possibly empty interval, and we argue as Kunen on p.74 that the union of all these intervals are dense: for each interval $J$ in the suslin line, there is a subinterval $K$ that does not contain any endpoint of the (countably many) intervals that appear as nodes in the tree constructed thus far, so for any such interval $I$ either $K\cap I=\emptyset$ or $K\subseteq I$. For each $\alpha<\gamma$, by denseness of the intervals in $\mathcal{I}_{\alpha}$, there is one interval $I_\alpha\in\mathcal{I}_{\alpha}$ that intersects $K$, but then $K\subseteq I_\alpha$. Also if $\alpha<\beta$ we must have $I_\alpha\supseteq I_\beta$, and therefore $K$ is contained in the intersection along the branch $\{I_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\gamma}$.

A small issue is that the intersection along a branch may not be an open interval, so we consider a maximal collection of disjoint open subintervals. I think this is equivalent to Kunen's $\mathcal{K}$.

Comment: thx for reply.
I just knew there exist the successor edition of kunen's set theory(1980) as simply 'Set Theory'(2011)